# Laravel 4 : tested with WhereIn() my pivot, Eloquent ORM

Tags: orm, pivot, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My tables :

```
Candidates :
    id
    first_name
    last_name
    email
    password

jobs :
    id
    name

candidate_job :
    id
    region_id
    candidate_id
```

I make research module. When i catch researched elements :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrB7R.png

When companie (recruiter) do research, I would like that the research module, retur the users (candidates) finded who had check the regions and jobs while signup

my request eloquent orm :

```
Candidate::with('regions')
           ->whereIn('candidate_region.region_id', $region)
           ->with('jobs')
           ->whereIn('candidate_job.job_id', $job)
           ->where('imavailable', '1')
           ->where('dateDisponible', '<=', $date)
           ->paginate(20);
```

it doesn't functional, the error returned is :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'candidate_region.region_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `candidates` where `candidate_region`.`region_id` in (?, ?, ?) and `candidate_job`.`job_id` in (?, ?, ?) and `imavailable` = ? and `dateDisponible` <= ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '4', 1 => '8', 2 => '40', 3 => '2', 4 => '8', 5 => '42', 6 => '1', 7 => '2013-06-10', ))
```

i don't understand, why ?

how to do ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel `->with(...)` is for eager loading, and you can't use eager-loaded relationships in your WHERE statements.

Use Fluent to run that query:

```
DB::table('candidates')
  ->join('candidate_region', 'candidates.id', '=', 'candidate_region.candidate_id'); 
  ->join('regions', 'candidate_region.region_id', '=', 'regions.id'); 
  ->join('candidate_job', 'candidates.id', '=', 'candidate_job.candidate_id'); 
  ->join('jobs', 'candidate_job.region_id', '=', 'jobs.id'); 
  ->whereIn('candidate_region.region_id',$region)
  ->whereIn('candidate_job.job_id',$job)
  ->where('imavailable', '1')
  ->where('dateDisponible', '<=', $date)
  ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: The problem of query builder is not return object regions/jobs for used since foreach. ex : `foreach($candidates->jobs as $jobs){ {{ $jobs->name }} } ==> return error    because fluent not return relationship

Comment: If you need the regions/jobs table, add them to the JOINs (see my edit). This will give you one big resultset with everything in columns, data from the cadidates/regions/jobs tables.

Comment: Thanks, but no return object (relationship) jobs or regions. var_dump return : http://paste.laravel.com/w1p and when we did vard_ump on request with `with()` `foreach($candidates-job as $jobs)` return : http://paste.laravel.com/w1q

Comment: As I said, the jobs won't be returned in a sub-object (relationships), they are returned as COLUMNS of your query. Look at the last columns from your first paste, those are from the JOBS table `public 'name' => string 'Charpentier-menuisier' (length=21)` Instead of getting nested sets, you get repeated rows for each candidate, with one repeated row for each region/job that matched.

Comment: im sorry, i had not uderstand. so, i must test each line for to know, if is it same ? it's very complicated :(

Comment: If you don't mind querying the DB twice, I could rewrite that query to do the job in three runs. 1- to get the candidates with the region and job IDs, then 2- get the regions and 3- get the jobs. That would give you your easy loops like you want.

Comment: Oki thanks, i favorable if i can use paginate on my request :)